# Search engine scraper-aggregator

Tags: python

For some reason, I completely lost my reasoning with this code. I can't hold this simple logic for too long in my head. Actually, I want to improve this code, making it a little concise. The `if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:` is just not a KISS thing. Please any suggesion to optimize and concise it?

```
source = request.POST.get('source')
queries = request.POST.get('term')

force = request.POST.get('rescan', False) # if checkbox is checked this becomes True

queries = [query.strip().lower() for query in queries.split(',')]
engines = ['alibaba', 'madeinchina', 'google', 'bing']
for src in engines:
    for query in queries:
        so = Source.objects.get(term__term=query, engine=src)
        if src == 'alibaba':
            if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:
                ali_results.delay(src, query)
        elif src == 'madeinchina':
            if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:
                made_results.delay(src, query)
        elif src == "google" or src == "bing":
            if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:
                search_engine_scraper.delay(query=query, source=src)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test `if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:` only fails when `so.scan_complete` is `True` and `force` is `False`. So it can be simplified to `if force or not so.scan_complete:`.

Also, since the test is identical for every `src`, it only needs to be done once:

```
for src in engines:
    for query in queries:
        so = Source.objects.get(term__term=query, engine=src)
        if force or not so.scan_complete:
            if src == 'alibaba':
                ali_results.delay(src, query)
            elif src == 'madeinchina':
                made_results.delay(src, query)
            elif src == "google" or src == "bing":
                search_engine_scraper.delay(query=query, source=src)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The `False` default for `force` isn't strictly necessary since `None`
  (the normal default) will be considered false in a boolean test.
- The `queries` parsing should be in a function as it's quite a reusable
  step.
- As has been said, the `if` condition can be rewritten much clearer and
  more like you'd explain the behaviour in natural language as well:
  "Run the scan if it's not yet complete, or if it has been forced."

The loop with the engines and queries should be structured a bit
differently:  At the moment the names of the engines are repeated
unnecessarily (the "scan complete" test as well).

What could be done however is to iterate over functions to be called,
all with the same interface, so then the loop can be replaced with
something simpler, e.g.:

```python
import itertools

source = request.POST.get('source')
queries = request.POST.get('term')
force = request.POST.get('rescan') # if checkbox is checked this becomes True

queries = [query.strip().lower() for query in queries.split(',')]

scraper = lambda src, query: search_engine_scraper.delay(source=src, query=query)
queries = [
    ('alibaba', lambda src, query: ali_results.delay(src, query)),
    ('madeinchina', lambda src, query: made_results.delay(src, query)),
    ('google', scraper),
    ('bing', scraper)
]

for (src, engine), query in itertools.product(engines, queries):
    so = Source.objects.get(term__term=query, engine=src)
    if not so.scan_complete or force:
        engine(src, query)
```

Of course it would be preferable to have the same calling convention for
all of the engines in the first place, so this additional wrapping
wouldn't be necessary (i.e. the list of `queries` would just list
`('alibaba', ali_results)` and the loop would always call
`engine.delay(src, query)`).  I'll leave that conversion to you.  Using
`itertools.product` is also up to taste I guess, but it makes for
compact code.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:
```

Before all the other ifs and nest them inside it:

```
if (so.scan_complete and force) or not so.scan_complete:
     if search_engine == x:
          ....
```

Or, even better, `continue` if the opposite is true, to reduce nesting.